# How to reformat/reindent Clojure code in Eclipse/CounterClockWise?

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

When I copy a piece of clojure code into Eclipse, how could I fix the format problem? In some text editors, there's reindent/format command or shortcut, is there a way to handle code formating in Eclipse?

Comment: In eclipse <CTRL>+<SHIFT>+F reformats code -at least in Java mode.- Does that not work?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for Clojure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for Select all,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for *indent the current line*.